# Using Processing language to visually represent XML. How do I draw an ellipse at each point the data ends/breaks?

Tags: java, xml, processing

I'm involved in a research project analysing how (if at all) architecture affects people's paths as they move around locations. So far we have used OpenCV Blob-tracker to successfully produce XML file data mapping the blobs as they move.
What I would like to do now, is draw an ellipse at each point the data begins and ends (to represent each person's start and end point).
Any help on reaching this conclusion would be most welcome.

Comment: If I understood this correctly, you're saving each tracked blob's position in an XML document. The question is how to draw an ellipse at the stored blob position for each xml position node ? I don't think I fully understood _each point the data begins and ends_. What's the structure of your xml ? (I imagine you a have a main node which contains a node for each blob which in turn it holds several positions and possible time related value)

Comment: Yes sorry I wasn't clearer. Here is a sample of the XML data:153, 491.8, 739.0, 23.82, 99.54, 494.5, 749.0, 23.48, 97.17, 496.3, 735.4, 22.78, 93.32, 484.5, 733.9, 24.24, 94.10, 492.6, 729.1, 24.00, 90.86, 492.7, 731.7, 23.25, 87.53, 491.8, 732.7, 22.97, 84.63, 490.3, 742.7, 22.37, 83.06, 471.0, 707.4, 22.12, 79.46, 489.6, 742.8, 21.44, 77.94, 480.3, 776.9, 21.48, 74.88, 481.7, 776.4, 21.35, 71.92, 482.0, 773.7, 21.47, 68.88, 483.8, 769.1, 21.44, 66.82, 482.9, 772.9, 20.61, 63.86, 482.8, 767.9, 20.66, 62.20, 483.8, 774.7, 19.98, 59.79, 469.0, 801.0, 19.27, 56.96, 484.5, 799.5, 18.53, 54.34

Comment: The XML doc is divided into many "paragraphs" like this. First and last 4 sets of numbers indicate time and position of the blob. It would be great to have say a red ellipse at the start time/position and blue at the end. I don't have a great understanding of Processing hence am a little stuck! Thanks for any help

Comment: Surely that isn't your xml structure. I see a list of numbers but nothing to delimit which part belongs where/what would the 4 sets be. Regarding red to blue and position transitioning/interpolation check out [lerp()](http://processing.org/reference/lerp_.html) for position elements and [lerpColor](http://processing.org/reference/lerpColor_.html) for colours. Please try to edit your answer and be a bit more clear. You're familiar with your data, but for anyone else on the site that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the structure of the data you have provided either. But in processing if you want to represent xml data (specifically position as coordinates on the screen and time as color) you first need to parse your xml file then map the values appropriately. Take a look at

http://processing.org/reference/XMLElement.html

http://processing.org/reference/map_.html

http://processing.org/reference/fill_.html

these should have about everything you need.

You can do something like this to represent xml as ellipses and colors.
say this is your xml, (im just making this up)

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <people>
   <person time="45.6" x="6.5" y="10.3"></person>
   ...
 </people>

XMLElement xml;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  int size = 10; //just a default size for the ellipse, maybe you want to pull this value from your data as well though

  xml = new XMLElement(this, "people.xml");
  int numPeople = xml.getChildCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++) {
    XMLElement person = xml.getChild(i);
    float time = person.getFloat("time"); 
    float xPos = person.getFloat("x"); 
    float yPos = person.getFloat("y"); 
    int personColor = map(time, 0, 100, 0, 255); //you will need some way of mapping your time values (i have no idea what the scale is, to a range of 0-255
    fill(personColor);
    ellipse(xPos, yPos, size, size);

  }
}
```

Based on the series of numbers you provided I would guess that your xml structure is much more complicated than what I provided in this example, if you want help parsing your specific data then please post a more complete example and description of the xml.